# php - Google Analytics Measurement Protocol POST request

Tags: php, google-analytics

I have issue when sending POST request from my server to google analytics.

I'm trying to send test (event,order etc.), but then I do not receive anything and when I look to events tracker in browser there is absolutely nothing happening...

---

**PHP code**

```
$x  =   [   
            'v'=>'1',
            't'=>'event',
            'tid'=>'.....',    // here goes my tracking ID
            'cid'=>'555',
            'ec'=>'video'
        ];

echo(google_a($x));


function google_a($x)                           {
    $x  = http_build_query($x);
    $ch = curl_init();
    $user_agent = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $user_agent);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,"https://www.google-analytics.com/collect");
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,array('Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded'));
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION,CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$x);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

    $server_output = curl_exec ($ch);

    curl_close ($ch);
    return($server_output);
}
```

---

I think that my CURL configuration isn't good. Can you help me with this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've solved this problem by adding this lines. They, as I understand, disable SSL connection verifying:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
```

So, I'm able to control google analytics from server :))

Answer (score 0):

What is the response from google? $server_output

Do this:

```
echo "<pre>"
print_r( $server_output )
```

And put here que feedback

Comment: `pre` isn't helping. Response is empty page, nothing even when sending to www.google-analytics.com/debug/collect